# How to assign a selected value to a listbox item so it can be removed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am currently working on a listbox that needs to have a function to remove/delete items from the listbox and ultimately the database. When an item(RegimeItem) is selected in the listbox, then the remove button is pressed the item is deleted from the database, that is what i want to happen.

The RequestedSelected part of the foreach statement in the `RemoveExercises` method of the controller is currently null, what i want to know is how do i make it so that it isn't?  From what i understand is that when the item is selected in the listbox that is not recognized as `RequestedSelected`

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(int? id, UserExerciseViewModel vmodel)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, vmodel) };
            user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id, RegimeItem regimeItem)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
            RestoreSavedState(model);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
                AddExercises(model, id);
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))
                RemoveExercises(model, id);              
            SaveState(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        void SaveState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
        {
            model.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", model.RequestedExercises.Select(p => p.RegimeItemID.ToString()).ToArray());
            model.AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises().ToList();
        }

    void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int? id)
    {
        foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
        {
            RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
            if (item != null)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                user.RegimeItems.Remove(item);
            }                
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        //RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex");
    }

        void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
        {
            model.RequestedExercises = new List<RegimeItem>();

            //get the previously stored items
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
            {
                string[] exIds = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
                var exercises = GetAllExercises().Where(p => exIds.Contains(p.ExerciseID.ToString()));
                model.AvailableExercises.AddRange(exercises);
            }
        }

private List<Exercise> GetAllExercises()
        {
            return db.Exercises.ToList();
        }

        private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user, UserExerciseViewModel model)
        {
            return db.Users
            .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)
            .SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems)
            .ToList();
        }
```

**Models**

```
 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
        } 
    }
    public class RegimeItem
    {
        public int RegimeItemID { get; set; }
        public Exercise RegimeExercise { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class UserExerciseViewModel
{
    public List<Exercise> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
    public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedExercise { get; set; }
    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
}
```

**View**(Segment only)

```
      <input type="submit" name="remove"
             id="remove" value="<<" />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
      @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise.Name", Model.RequestedSelected))
  </td>
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Chris' help i have made progress with the controller and i have updated the view also.  It is still not removing individual items, it is returning a blank list and it does not save to the db either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never actually persisting anything. Unless you call `SaveChanges` somewhere, all of what you're doing just goes away on the next request.

Comment: Apologies, i missed that out when i was copying the code over as there are a few commented out section between the lines

Comment: I think you still have some copy paste errors. Your call to `db.SaveChanges` is now inside your `foreach` loop, as well as a call to `RedirectToAction`. If that's the code you actually had, then the loop would only ever iterate once. However, `RedirectToAction` does nothing unless it's *returned*, so that bit of code is effectively useless.

Comment: Thanks Chris, i just updated it. Would you happen to know why `model.RequestedSelected` on the foreach line is null?

Comment: Your `ListBoxFor` call references `RequestedExcercises`, not `RequestedSelected`.

Comment: I believe that is because `RequestedExercises` is the list of available Exercises (RegimeItems).  Requested selected is supposed to be the item once it is selected, im not 100% on that.  Right now, the view returns the list of exercises for the user.  If i change it to `RequestedExercises` it returns a list of all the chosen exercises for all of the users.

Comment: No, I mean you should have the following in your view: `@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise.Name", Model.RequestedSelected))`

Comment: Thanks Chris, it's looking alot better now it just seems to remove all of the exercises though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77634/discussion-between-chris-pratt-and-nilmag).